# Comparing to items in an Array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, compare

alright guys, this should be an easy one...

I have an int array and I want to see if the the numbers in the array are in succession.

For some reason when I do this (below) my array goes from int values to ascii and gets all funky and doesn't work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  In this exampleit should return true.

```
int numArray[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

for( int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
{

    if ( numArray[i] == numArray[i+1] - 1 )
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: `int numArray[5]...; numArray.size()` is definitely not C++. Please post code the actual code that you're having trouble with.

Comment: The code you posted is nonsensical, as is your comment about ASCII. Please post an **actual**, **complete** program that demonstrates your problem. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: C++ arrays are not objects like in JavaScript. They don't have a method called size. You'll have to hard code the size of the array or store it in a variable.

Comment: The code returns `true` http://codepad.org/YhLVHmsn

Comment: Argh, it does return true, via todda. Thanks!!!!!  I think there is a problem else where.

Comment: I think the problem was that you were trying to use the size method on an array in C++. Didn't that generate a compile time error?

Comment: "my array goes from int values to ascii and gets all funky and doesn't work" is not a very useful error description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write something like this, a little simpler to read.

```
bool issequential(const int* array, int size)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i)
        if (array[i - 1] + 1 != array[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I I hate getting caught up in the easy stuff.

Comment: Oh thanks, in reality i never used python before, would be nice to see how is this in python, can u provide it just for the sake of curiosity?